# How to Display data from a plist using cocos2d iphone?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, plist

I am creating a game of questions and answers for iphone using cocos2d, and I wonder how can I do to display the question on the screen using ccLabel seeking data from a plist. can someone help me with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is grab it from your resources bundle, and save it into a dictionary.  From there you have access to every value inside of your plist. That can be achieved with something like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myList.plist"];
NSDictionary *plistData = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath] retain];
```

Then when you're ready to display the question just use the [plistData objectForKey: ] method.  Do you need help setting up the label also?

Comment: Yes I'm finding it difficult, would help me with an example, thank you already helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Sure man.  You want to set it up like this:

```
CCLabel* questionLabel = [CCLabel labelWithString:@"Your Question" 
                               fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:64];


CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

label.position = ccp( size.width /2 , size.height/2 );

[self addChild: questionLabel];
```

That'll display your label in the middle of the screen.  You can change the position, font, etc. The way you access your data from the plist is determined by exactly how you set it up.  But using the technique I gave your earlier you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: pob21 obrigado pela ajuda, consegui resolver parcialmente o meu problema, eu consegui carregar os dados do plist, agora tenho que montar um plist mais elaborado, com alguns níveis, por exemplo: categoria fácil com várias perguntas e respostas, vê-lo mais tarde.

Comment: You're welcome and as for the different difficulties, the simplest  method would be to just use 3 different plist(easy, medium, hard).